# VS code автофокус(позиционирование курсора) как настроить?

Tags: visual-studio-code

При запуске скрипта не удобно что фокус(курсор) остается в окне редактора, а не перемещается в терминал(консоль) где скрипт запущен, особенно когда выполнение скрипта начинается с ввода данных с клавиатуры  :(

Можно настроить так:

- запустил скрипт - фокус и курсор в терминале,
- скрипт отработал или прервал его работу - фокус и курсор в редакторе

Answer (score 1):

Я искал подобный функционал, раздражает что при переключении фокус оказывается не в терминале а всё ещё на выборе инстанса терминалов.

В настройках достаточно выбрать одиночное нажатие (по дефолту 2й клик)
[image: Выбрать однократный клик при выборе терминала]

Answer (score 0):

В настройках расширения Python'а нашёл только. Как сделать чтобы после выполнения - не знаю.
Можно нажать *crtl* + *1* чтобы переключить фокус на первый редактор.
Нажать *crtl* + *~* чтобы переключить фокус на терминал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]